# Microsoft Graph API: 400 when using "invite" endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, http-status-code-400, invite

I want to send an invitation by mail to customers, so they can download a file from our SharePoint. The request is like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{siteId}}/drives/{{driveId}}/root:/Prueba/prueba.txt:/microsoft.graph.invite
```

With body:

```
{
  "recipients": [
    {"email": "mail1@mail.com"},
    {"email": "mail2@mail.com"}
  ],
  "message": "Download your file",
  "requireSignIn": true,
  "sendInvitation": true,
  "roles": [ "read" ]
}
```

If I fill up "recipients" with mails from the organization, everything goes ok.

But when I use external mails (gmail, hotmail, other companies mails, etc), the response is 400 with this body:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose we need to configure our SharePoint in a certain way, but Microsoft support couldn't help us. Could anyone suggest any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i havent played much with invite. Please check the Microsoft docs. But I remember about the create/share link (programmatically using MS Graph) in onedrive where you can share it with someone outside of your org. But keep in mind that for OneDrive for Business and SharePoint, the Shares API always requires authentication and cannot be used to access anonymously shared content without a user context.

Comment: Thaks, @Dev. I've opened a similar question about **createLink**... same issue there using scope:anonymous. So, is not possible using such features from a batch process? We don't want any user logging; just a java batch process sending links to externar clients.

Comment: You can make this call work by going to the [Sharepoint Admin Center](https://admin.microsoft.com/sharepoint?page=home&modern=true)--> Sites --> Active Sites --> Select the site which you are using and click on the 3 dots just below "Active sites" heading and select sharing and make it anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the other mail Accounts like gmail,yahoo etc in the recipients property but before that you need to modify your site setting. Go to  [Sharepoint Admin Center](https://admin.microsoft.com/sharepoint?page=home&modern=true)--> Sites --> Active Sites --> Select the site which you are using and click on the 3 dots just below "Active sites" heading and select sharing and make it anyone.